roots of unity in non archimedean valued field
Let $(K, |\cdot|)$ be a non archimedean valued field such that char(K)=char($\kappa_K$) Show that if $x,y\in K$ are distinct roots of unity then $|x-y|=1$, here $\kappa_K$ is residue field
It is easy to see that $|x-y|\leq1$
and im noticed that if $|x-y|<1$ then $|x^n-y^n|<1$ for all n
any idea for this
Thk

When $a^n = 1$ and $|a-1| < 1$, and assuming $n$ is not divisible by $p$ when the residue field has positive characteristic $p$, use Hensel's lemma with
$f(x) = x^n - 1$ to show that $a = 1$.

But Hensel's Lemma only guarantees the existence of a solution; this means that if 1 is a simple solution modulo pp, we can lift this solution to Zp. So, how can we prove that there are no other solutions for x^n-1=0 in Z_p ?

If you believe Hensel's lemma only guarantees the existence of a solution, and not also its uniqueness, then you have either read a weak form of Hensel's lemma or you did not read the proof of it carefully enough.  When $f(x) \in \mathcal O_K[x]$, $|f(a)| = 1$, and $|f'(a)| < 1$, Hensel's lemma says there is a unique $r \in \mathcal O_K$ such that (i) $f(r) = 0$ and (ii) $|r - a| < 1$. Thus when $n$ doesn't vanish in the residue field, the unique solution to $x^n = 1$ in $1 + \mathfrak m_K$ is $1$: it works and the root there is unique by Hensel's lemma, so there are no more roots there.

In https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf, see Theorems 2.1, 4.1, and 10.5.
